# Using PHP to communicate with MYSQL in AWS-EC2 and RDS

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I am trying to access my MYSQL database from my EC2 instance using PHP and it keeps coming up with the error in the browser (below).  I can access my MYSQL database on the RDS instance when i access my EC2 from the console.  Please can someone advise?

```
 define('DB_USER', "myUserName"); // db user
 define('DB_PASSWORD', "myPassword"); // db password (mention your db password here)
 define('DB_DATABASE', "myDatabaseName"); // database name
 define('DB_SERVER', "myEndPoint"); 



 // Connect to database
 $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE); 

 if($mysqli->connect_errno) { 
     echo 'connection to RDS error';
 }else{
     echo 'connection to RDS success!'
 }
```

Broswer readout:

```
 This page isn’t working

 ip.ip.ip.ip is currently unable to handle this request.
 HTTP ERROR 500
```

Comment: 500 error, could be anything.  Could be it's not connecting, it could be that you don't have the php mysql module installed, etc.  You really need to take a look at your error logs to get more information.

Comment: where can i access the error log please?

Comment: Depends on your setup, apache/nginx, etc.   But you should be able to find it in the /var/log/ directory, possibly something like /var/log/apache2, you should see an error.log file within.